# Setting TopAppBar on page inside an inner frame places the app bar at the top of the window (good), but still takes space (bad)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

When I have a page with an CommandBar set on Page.TopAppBar (and that page in an inner page on another page), the UI element appears at the top of the window (which is what I expected and want).

However, the page on the inner page gets "space" taken out of it - as if the CommandBar is actually on it.

I tried a couple of things, the only thing that kind'a works is playing with margins, but even that seems to have weird artifacts (and anyway is not how I want to solve this).

Here's the XAML for the outer page:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="100" BorderBrush="Pink" BorderThickness="3">
        <Frame x:Name="frame" />
     </Border>
</Grid>
```

And here's the XAML form the inner page:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar>

    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Grid Background="Black">

</Grid>
```

Here's what the UI looks like - as you can see, the inner page has a bunch of space "taken" out as if the appbar is actually located on it.:

[image: Image showing the space being taken on the inner page]

Comment: Actually, i doubt that it is a good practice too use a page inside another page in the way you did, that seems to be source of the problem. Frames are supposed to be container for pages.

Comment: The inner page is inside a frame.... I am just trying to show a very simple example of what happens when you do the whole Win10 hamburger thing - you have pages inside frames. This just shows the problem simplified.

Comment: Problem with your design is that you have margins around the page (frame). The hamburger thing is usually implemented with an SplitView in that scenario, content of SplitView does not have margins neither. I'm not saying the behavior is perfect but you have no problem if you do it as the usual way.

Comment: Yes you do - this whole problem started because when I have a splitview with a hamburger, the same exact behavior is observed. I was just trying to create a simplified version that shows the exact same issue.

Comment: Just remove the margin from the border element, what would be the problem then?

Comment: The margin applies *outside* the border. If I had Padding, it would have been inside the border. Removing the margin has exactly the same effect (empty space), only the frame takes the whole area...

Comment: Yes, the empty space would be there as long as you have an app bar. The idea behind the design is that a page is supposed fit the window (at least vertically) so should not have any visual element between the page and window in vertical direction so that the app bar fits that empty space. it wasn't like that in PREVIEW versions, we had to add a custom margin to make that empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  container, just put CommandBar inside your Page in inner Frame. Put CommandBar in the bottom to make sure it overlays other element in the inner Page.

Final code should look like:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
<!-- Content here -->


    <CommandBar>

    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you do that, the keyboard goes over it when it comes up. That's why I put it in the TopAppBar